# how to add image when the checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an image when the checkbox is checked, I'm trying adicionala to append but could not add someone could help me?

HTML

```css
.hovereffect {
width:100%;
height:100%;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
cursor:default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
top:0;
left:0;
opacity:0;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
transition:all .4s ease-in-out
}

.hovereffect img {
display:block;
position:relative;
-webkit-transition:all .4s linear;
transition:all .4s linear;
}

.hovereffect h2 {
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
font-size:17px;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
-webkit-transform:translatey(-100px);
-ms-transform:translatey(-100px);
transform:translatey(-100px);
-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
padding:10px;
}

.hovereffect a.info {
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#fff;
border:1px solid #fff;
background-color:transparent;
opacity:0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
margin:50px 0 0;
padding:7px 14px;
}

.hovereffect a.info:hover {
box-shadow:0 0 5px #fff;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
-ms-transform:scale(1.0);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.0);
transform:scale(1.0);
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
opacity:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2,.hovereffect:hover a.info {
opacity:1;
filter:alpha(opacity=100);
-ms-transform:translatey(0);
-webkit-transform:translatey(0);
transform:translatey(0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
-webkit-transition-delay:.2s;
transition-delay:.2s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <div class="hovereffect">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay">
                     <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-primary cke">
                          <input type="checkbox" value="nao"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                        </label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    
    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked') == true){
      $("hovereffect").append('<img id="heart" class="img-responsive" src="../images/heart.png">');
      return;
    }
  });
</script>
```

how do I can do this to add an image of the heart when the checkbox is checked

Comment: Your jQuery selector is wrong. Replace `$("hovereffect")` with `$(".hovereffect")` (add the dot at the beginning)

Comment: are you trying to target an element of type hovereffect or an element with a classname of hovereffect? There is a difference and I suspect part of your problem is the missing `.`

Comment: Wrap your `$('input[type=checkbox]').change` in `$(document).ready`

Comment: `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')` is ***always*** true, it's a jQuery collection, you wanted `if (this.checked)`

Comment: sorry i did not see dot. but now I put the dot and it was not too

Answer (score 0):

Your class is hovereffect so jquery syntax will be

`$(".hovereffect")` instead of

```
 $("hovereffect")
```